# Marketing Cloud: Are Data Views Live?

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-views

I've been of the understanding that the data views in SFMC contain live data. For instance, if I query _clicks, wait five minutes, and query it again, I'll get new results from within the last five minutes. I'm assuming that the data viewsare updated via API calls.

Is there documentation anywhere proving this is an expected, normal behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation on DataViews isn't great. This is always what I reference: [**Data Views**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/data_views/)

Previously I queried DataViews to check if someone had been successfully unsubscribed from a publication list through a landing page. I ran the query before and after the unsubscribe test and the value changed. This was within a few minutes. So it appears that the DataViews references live data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That's a great point of reference, but I was hoping there was something concretely defining the SFMC data views as real-time. I ran that same test and got live results, but it'd be nice to reference documentation on this specifically. Thanks again!

Comment: If your answer ends up being the only answer, as in there is no concrete documentation out there, I'll be sure to accept your answer.

Comment: Hey Jacob. Have had a few guys in the office who have confirmed that Data Views are 'Live', meaning that data will update those tables up to a few minutes after an action has been taken (email send etc). They also can't seem to find any documentation to support this.